# Jwt authentication on node-js and react -js

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am working on jwt authentication based projects and I want to  store the token which is created on user 's login request but this token can be decoded easily so where I have to store these token ?

```
//code to create token and cookie

const createToken=(id)=>{
return jwt.sign({id},secretkey);}

{....some code are written here.....}

const token= createToken(userid);
res.cookie('jwts',token,{httpOnly:true,maxAge:1000*60*60,sameSite:'lax'})
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it feels like your JWT flow isn't clear. The token can be decoded - but it will only reveal some payload data and header - which doesn't contain any sensitive data.

**Token's generation and explanation:**
A JWT Token is formed of **Header**, **Payload** & **Signature**.

The header is metadata about the token itself.
The payload can be encoded in the token, i.e. the data e.g. user's Id.
Signature is created using header, payload, & the SECRET stored at the server. This process is called Signing. This 'SECRET' is what helps us to validate the signature's authenticity.

***Well, so how do we make sure the data isn't modified?***

A verification process is done at the server where JWT's header, payload, and secret are used to create a test signature. This signature is matched with the original signature (existing inside the JWT already) - then the data has not been modified.
Without secret - no one can manipulate JWT. That is, the verification will fail if the signatures do not match.

**Token Storage:**
There is some debate about whether to store the token in **cookies** or **local-storage** since both are prone to hacker attacks.

**Login Flow:**

- The client sends a request to the server (POST - login).
- The server validates the user and returns a JWT token in response if the provided credentials are valid.
- The JWT token is stored in localStorage / cookies depending on the preferred choice (I prefer localStorage).

Comment: i know all these stuff but i am confused on where to store the token ,generally i store it in cookies ,is it safe to store there  ?

Comment: @teksojr Yes, it's totally safe. Using cookies over localStorage is actually beneficial.
Since, if you're using localStorage - it is prone to XSS attacks (Cross-Site Scripting: It just basically allows the attacker to inject malicious code using JS and can easily read the localStorage).

Use HTTPOnly cookies - that makes it so the browser can only send & receive the cookie - but not access/modify it in any way.

They may be prone to other kinds of attacks e.g. brute-force attacks, etc. You can read about them in articles dedicated to that.

But in the end, yes they are safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send that token along with the API requests from client. I used to store in clients internal storage and used to send that token for each and every API call.

Comment: thnks for your response